# gracefully shutdown http server

Tags: node.js

I write a http + websocket(socket.io) server, and catch SIGINT to stop it.

But I can't stop it gracefully. eg:

in a konsole window, I typed in:
>

> xxx ~$ npm start
>
> info  - socket.io started
>
> server started at :80
>
> new web socket connection !
>
> ^C                                   ###  PRESS CTRL+C HERE
>
> xxx ~$ ^C--- SIGINT RECIVED --- #  <-- WTF??!! ( I have already been dropped to shell
>
> xxx ~$ ps -f
>
> ```
> UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
> GongT    18776  2281  0 17:37 pts/11   00:00:00 /bin/bash
> GongT    31365     1  0 21:24 pts/11   00:00:00 node main.js
> GongT    31548 18776  0 21:24 pts/11   00:00:00 ps -f
>                  # ^ look at PPID of node process
> ```
>
> xxx ~$ kill -SIGINT 31365
>
> --- SIGINT RECIVED ---
>
> xxx ~$ kill -SIGINT 31365
>
> --- SIGINT RECIVED ---
>
> xxx ~$                               #  now I disconnect from client(web browser)
>
> server stopped. bye~

My signal handler like that:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function (){
    console.log(' --- SIGINT RECIVED --- ');
    if(isServerRunning){
        server.close();
        isServerRunning = false;
        setInterval(function(){
            if(checkEveryThingFinished()){
                console.log('server stopped. bye~');
                process.exit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

#### My question is :

why I was dropped to shell without end the process, and how to prevent this?

(just waitting until `process.exit()`)